# Magento products not showing up consistently in frontend

Tags: php, magento, indexing, catalog

I have Magento site running with 20000 plus products. Sometimes it does not show the products in the frontend. It says "There are no products matching the selection", but the products are still there in the backend site.

I know I have to run re-indexing process, and whenever I complete the re-indexing process all products are there in the frontend.

So now, my question is: Why this is happening again and again? This is now fourth time I faced this problem. I want to know the real causes of this issue. I am very afraid.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked the system.log and exception.log after noticing the missing products? I came across a similar problem once, and the logs where full of information about deadlocks, timeouts and inconsistency in the database. As far as I know, this kind of things happen on some servers (its probably a db issue) with certain extensions. Are you using any special modules related with product tables? (loyalty points? extended options?)

Comment: Could you give us more information about what indexes are enabled? Us it caused after some import process? Maybe you have some ERP integration or custom import extension that may broke the indexing process?

Comment: all indexes are enabled. I imported some products before but not now and I just updated some php file for customization.

Comment: if you ran to this then you must re-index your indexes, this is typical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most likely cuplrits are caching and indexing problems (unless of course you are using a clustered database, in which case that is probably the culprit). If it's feasible on your site (or on a dev environment, which I am sure you had the foresight to create), disable Magento's caching temporarily and see if that alleviates the issue. Also try disabling the flat_catalog settings to see if that is having an effect.

Also make sure that your browser cache is set to always refresh from the server.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to setup your cronjobs to re-run the indexes.  Certainly with prices, the custom price indexes are only valid for a set period of time, then the cronjob extends those periods if the Catalog Price Rule is still active.

Here is a wiki [post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) on the process of setting up your cronjobs.

Note that cron itself can cause problems, so as Joseph suggests, make sure you have a dev and staging environment setup that mirrors production so that you can check the configuration.